# How can I calculate the discharge flow rate of compressor of 1 HP?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Outlet nozzle - 1 1/4 inch
Cut off pressure - 8 bar
Tank capacity - 35 ltrs

How can I calculate the discharge flow rate?
Based on the outlet nozzle, discharge rate will vary.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: i have used ideal gas law. in that ( PV=mRT)  left hand side i have replaced volume as volume flow rate , right hand replaced mass as mass flow rate . but final result, unit, have come as J/Kg. is that right

Comment: Have you considered Bernoulli's equation?

Answer (score 0):

Horsepower is the product of pressure times mass flow rate. Mind the units, and solve for the flow rate. This assumes 100% compressor efficiency, so it will be an upper limit to the true answer.

Comment: thanks for response, i want to calculate the flow rate for the tank which is having 8 bar pressure of 35 litre capacity  tank

Comment: We know that. You wrote it in your question. Instead, edit your question, show what you have done and where you are stuck.